# How to calculate x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 for rectangle

Tags: c#, image, geometry

I need to find the position of a rectangle on the image. Rectangle points positions are fallowing [X1, Y1, X2, Y2] `[7608,1638,7663,1680]` also I know Image `Height: 4096` and `Width: 8192` on which I need to plot the rectangle. The rectangle will be hosted in GeoServer as a WFS layer. However, to visualize the shape I need to calculate x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5 somethink like this [[7047,2451],[7021,2266],[6749,2231],[6777,2392],[7047,2451]] from above-given values. How can I do that? I know that x5 ,y5 will be the same as x1, y1 as it is a closing one.

I believe for many of you this is a very basic question but for me it is complicated.

Comment: You need to show us how to create your rectangle. you should not have to do more than 5 parameters, `Color`, `X`,`Y`, `Height` and `Width`. If you are using GDI [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawRectangle_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the method you are looking for

Comment: A control has 4 properties 1) Top 2) Left 3) Height 4) Width  The y axis starts at top of screen with positive value going towards bottom of screen, while x positive is to the right.  So top is minY, left is minX.  The width and height are same as your values.

Comment: What do `minX` and `maxX` (and the associated `Y` counterparts) mean? I would have expected `maxX - minX = Width`, but it doesn't. I guess this is not a right-angled rectangle, but even still one wouldn't fit in those bounds with those dimensions (as far as I can tell)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the points `minX`, `maxX`, `minY`, `maxY`, and if we're talking about a right-angled, level rectangle, then the four points would typically be:

```
(minX, minY)-► ■ ═════════════════ ■ ◄-(maxX, minY)
               ║                   ║
               ║                   ║
               ║                   ║  Height = maxY - minY
               ║                   ║
               ║                   ║
(minX, maxY)-► ■ ═════════════════ ■ ◄-(maxX, maxY) 

                Width = maxX - minX
```

This assumes that we're dealing with rectangles where `(0, 0)` is the top-left corner, which is typical in windowed applications. Adjust accordingly if GeoServer rectangles are laid out differently.

Comment: For integers `Width = maxX - minX + 1` and correspondingly for the height.

Comment: Think of the case of finite positions on a screen (like a console window) and set `minX=5` and `maxX=5`. Is the window 1 unit wide or 0?

Comment: @ja72 Any rectangle with `minX == maxX` is really a `Line` (or a `Point` if `minY == maxY` is also true), with a with of `0`. Lines have no width, and points have no width or length.

Comment: When counting with integers, the width of a point or a line is 1, sInce it has a finite size on the screen. If the positions are `float` then you need `maxX-minX+(one pixel width)`.

Comment: @ja72 Can you provide a link to some documentation? For my part, the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` struct has a [`FromLTRB`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,aaed39969a75ea4f,references) method that returns a rectangle based on dimensions, where `Width` is calculated by `Right - Left` (and `Height` is `Bottom - Top`). Also, in winforms, all controls have similar relationships between corner points and the width/height. In mathematics it's also a standard that a `Line` is one-dimensional and a `Point` has no dimensions, only a location.

Comment: I found it in [Console.WindowWidth](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/19f2a20d8adf969c.html) where it is calculated as `Right-Left + 1`. One character position makes a huge difference in the Console output, whereas one pixel does not. I am still surprised the calculation in `Control` would be erroneous like that.

Comment: Look at [this imgur](https://i.imgur.com/jhRRnbb.png) for the reason why the +1